# How to use find_in_set with join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

I have 4 tables, and I want to fetch data from all the tables, I can do this by fetching data one by one from each table but I want to do it by using JOIN.

[Main Table (which contains ids of other table data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJon0.png)

[2, 3, 4 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSrAz.png)

now I want to fetch these fields.

from Table 1 (Main Table) - franchise_name, franchise_phone

from Table 2 (State Table) - state_name

from Table 3 (City Table)  - city_name

from Table 4 (Area Table) - area_name

the first table contains ids of everything which I need to fetch from other tables.
but area_id in the main table is inserted as a string in the same row separated by (,) in field franchise_area.

I tried using FIND_IN_SET but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Read all 1-1 referred data using Join, cycle through data exploding area_id column

```
area_id -------> ($value = explode($row->area_id, ',')
```

then read data from database and insert into response array (or object).
Of course all of this operation must be done into the model...